# Remove or ignore character from reader

Tags: java

i am reading all characters into stream. I am reading it with inputStream.read. This is java.io.Reader inputStream.
How can i ignore special characters like @ when reading into buffer.

code

```
private final void FillBuff() throws java.io.IOException
  {
     int i;
     if (maxNextCharInd == 4096)
        maxNextCharInd = nextCharInd = 0;

     try {
        if ((i = inputStream.read(nextCharBuf, maxNextCharInd,
                                            4096 - maxNextCharInd)) == -1)
        {
           inputStream.close();
           throw new java.io.IOException();
        }
        else
           maxNextCharInd += i;
        return;
     }
     catch(java.io.IOException e) {
        if (bufpos != 0)
        {
           --bufpos;
           backup(0);
        }
        else
        {
           bufline[bufpos] = line;
           bufcolumn[bufpos] = column;
        }
        throw e;
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a custom `FilterReader`.

```
class YourFilterReader extends FilterReader{
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException{
        int read;
        do{
            read = super.read();
        } while(read == '@');

        return read; 
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException{
        int read = super.read(cbuf, off, len);

        if (read == -1) {
            return -1;
        }

        int pos = off - 1;
        for (int readPos = off; readPos < off + read; readPos++) {
            if (read == '@') {
                continue;
            } else {
                pos++;
            }

            if (pos < readPos) {
                cbuf[pos] = cbuf[readPos];
            }
        }
        return pos - off + 1;
    }
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - FilterReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html)
- [BCRDF - Skipping Invalid XML Character with ReaderFilter](http://info.tsachev.org/2009/05/skipping-invalid-xml-character-with.html)

**On the same topic :**

- [filter/remove invalid xml characters from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215506/filter-remove-invalid-xml-characters-from-stream)

Comment: Yep, a new Decorator is the way to go.

Comment: Just a note. In the second method the arguments are missing. ;)

Comment: I think the first line within the loop should be `if (cbuf[readPos] == '@') {`.  The `read` variable that is being tested now stays unchanged for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 5):

All those readers, writers and streams implement the *Decorator* pattern. Each decorator adds additional behaviour and functionality to the underlying implementation.

A solution for you requirement could be a FilterReader:

```
public class FilterReader implements Readable, Closeable {
  private Set<Character> blacklist = new HashSet<Character>();
  private Reader reader;      

  public FilterReader(Reader reader) {
    this.reader = reader;
  }

  public void addFilter(char filtered) {
    blacklist.add(filtered);
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws IOException {reader.close();}

  @Override
  public int read(char[] charBuf) {
    char[] temp = new char[charBuf.length];
    int charsRead = reader.read(temp);
    int index = -1;
    if (!(charsRead == -1)) {
      for (char c:temp) {
        if (!blacklist.contains(c)) {
          charBuf[index] = c;
          index++;
         }
      }
    }
    return index;
  }

}
```

---

Note - the class `java.io.FilterReader` is a decorator with zero functionality. You can extend it or just ignore it and create your own decorator (which I prefer in this case).

Comment: With the `read(char[])` method, I think you should keep reading until the `charBuf` is full. Your implementation just reads the valid elements in the next `charbuf.length` elements. Nice implementation overall with the `Set` - perhaps I'd include another constructor with a `Set` parameter - but that's not really that important here.

Comment: I would extend `java.io.FilterReader`, it could be useful to keep your class as a Reader, and explicitly say that it's a reader created to filter an input character stream. And polymorphism would still be available.  And in your case, you can't encapsulate your class into another Reader, because it's not another Reader.

Comment: Yikes - `Reader` is not an interface but an abstract class. Changed the implementation...

Comment: `BufferedReader` also **is-a** `Reader` and **has-a** `Reader`. It's the point of readers/writers/inputstreams/outputstreams you can encapsulate them all.

Comment: @Colin - I deleted the silly sentence, I wanted to make a different point: usually we do this pattern with interfaces but unfortunatly SUN decided to implement an abstract class instead of a `Reader` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement an own inputstream derived from InputStream. Then override the read methods so that they filter a special character out of the stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final void FillBuff() throws java.io.IOException
{
 int i;
 if (maxNextCharInd == 4096)
    maxNextCharInd = nextCharInd = 0;

 try {
    Reader filterReader = new FilterReader(inputStream) {
        public int read() {
            do {
                result = super.read();
            } while (specialCharacter(result));
            return result;
        }
    };
    if ((i = filterReader.read(nextCharBuf, maxNextCharInd,
                                        4096 - maxNextCharInd)) == -1)
    {
       inputStream.close();
       throw new java.io.IOException();
    }
    else
       maxNextCharInd += i;
    return;
 }
 catch(java.io.IOException e) {
    if (bufpos != 0)
    {
       --bufpos;
       backup(0);
    }
    else
    {
       bufline[bufpos] = line;
       bufcolumn[bufpos] = column;
    }
    throw e;
 }
}
```

Comment: and what is specialCharacter method?