# How to parse a reader in Java before sending to a method who use this reader

Tags: java, google-visualization, bufferedreader

Here is the code and what I want to do

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (new URL (url).openStream()));

/*
 * I want to do this code before sending to CsvDataSourceHelper
 * but Reader has no method replace ^^
 *
 * reader.replace("+", "").replace("%", "");
 */

DataTable dataTable = CsvDataSourceHelper.read(reader, column, false);
```

url is a string with a url of a **csv file**
column is an ArrayList of ColumnDescription
DataTable and **CsvDataSourceHelper** are classes created by Google
**reader** is a csv file

[DataTable Documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/datatable/DataTable)
[CsvDataSourceHelper Documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_javadocs/com/google/visualization/datasource/util/CsvDataSourceHelper)

**reader** receives a **csv** file from the internet
I must **send** this csv file to **CsvDataSourceHelper**
The problem is that the csv file is **incorrectly formatted**, I would **remove the + and %** before sending to **CsvDataSourceHelper**
I could do it after, with a for loop on dataTable, but the problem is that the file is incorrectly formatted so CsvDataSourceHelper **does not give me the right result**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should likely implement a [`FilterReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) that does this conversion.

There is [example code at java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/AsimpleFilterReaderthatstripsHTMLtagsoutofastreamofcharacters.htm) that strips html tags.  If you only need to strip two characters, it should be much simpler.

Comment: Thank you, i dit not know FilterReader.
But i used this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607010/remove-or-ignore-character-from-reader) instead your link